# ASP.Net Membership Cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to know what is the idea behind cookies in the Membership, a method is called:

```
Membership.GetUser();
```

This method returns all the user information, this method doesn't access the database but access a cookie stored on my pc, i am trying to know how this cookie is stored, and how can i access this cookie and manipulate it.

Here is my problem:

I have a forum that i want to integrate to my website, the forum users Membership while my website doesn't, my website use a simple username password table. i have altered some procedures related to Membership Login, and still when i enters the forum it logs me as an admin because i was using it before changing anything in the database, i have trace the cookies all i found was 6 cookies with with no subkeys, yet when the method above is called it gets all the info. I want to know where are they got from.

Edit:
I am wrong it does access the database, my question now **can i override the getuser method in the Memberships and assign another procedure to it**.

Comment: The membership provider has a complete API for manipulating members. Why would you want to manipulate the cookie? (Ie. help us solve your problem, not your initial attempt at a solution. See *[XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect.  `Membership.GetUser()` does in fact access the database.  It pulls the data from the membership tables.  This data is NOT stored in a cookie.  The only thing stored in the cookie is the username of the user, and an authentication ticket.

Edit:

Based on your update, you need to implement a custom membership provider to work with your authentication.  If the forum users Membership, then you have no other choice, otherwise you will have to rewrite the forum.

It appears you are confused by the fact there are no membership tables in your database.  This is most likely because the membership connection string points to a different database than you are using for your data.  This typically gets auto-generated for you and is stored under App_Data folder in your project folder.

Edit2:

Based on your additional edit, yes.  You can do whatever you want.  But you need to implement a custom Membership provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/f1kyba5e.aspx

Comment: Your exactly right, can you answer my question above ? thanks.

Comment: Also: a custom membership provider could be (mostly) a thin wrapper around an existing one. You do not need a completely green field implementation to add a little logic in one place (providing you ensure that change is not inconsistent with the operation of methods you are just reusing).

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1647173.aspx

If they are separate applications you can have them share session by ensuring the same app pool for both applications